# Compound Predicate Not Working with MagicalRecord Fetch

Tags: objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

My data model is as follows...

MNMerchant <-- (relationship categories) -->> MNCategory (categoryId)

MNCategory has an inverse relationship to MNMerchant called "merchants".

My view controller displays merchants on a mapview.  The first fetch that limits the results by the map's geographical bounds works fine...

```
NSMutableArray *filters = [NSMutableArray array];

NSMutableString *rectPred = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"lng > %lf AND lng < %lf AND lat < %lf AND lat > %lf", northWestCorner.longitude, southEastCorner.longitude, northWestCorner.latitude, southEastCorner.latitude];

[filters addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:rectPred]];

NSArray *merchantsInRect = [[MNMerchant MR_findAll] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:filters]];
```

My sample/test data correctly returns 3 merchants.  Here's log output...

```
FILTERS = (
    "lng > -105.961313 AND lng < -104.2035 AND lat < 41.048607 AND lat > 38.927436"
)
RESULTS = 3 MERCHANTS IN RECT
```

I then take the categories for the fetched merchants and populate a menu used to filter the map by category.  The menu only ever shows the valid categories for the merchants within the displayed map geographic bounds.

```
NSMutableArray *categories = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:nil];
for(MNMerchant *merchant in merchantsInRect){
    for(MNCategory *category in merchant.categories){
        if([categories indexOfObject:category] == NSNotFound){
            [categories addObject:category];
        }
    }
}

[_tray setCategories:categories];
```

The user can then turn off and on these categories, which enables a second fetch to be made with an appended set of filters...

```
NSArray *merchantsForDisplay;

if(useFilters){
    //FILTER MERCHANTS
    if(_tray.selectedCategories.count == 0){
        [filters addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"merchantId = 0"]];
    }else{
        [filters addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY categories.categoryId IN %@", [_tray.selectedCategories valueForKey:@"categoryId"]]];
    }

    merchantsForDisplay = [MNMerchant MR_findAllSortedBy:@"sortName" ascending:YES withPredicate:[NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:filters]];

}else{

    merchantsForDisplay = merchantsInRect;

}
```

Logged output when enabling and disabling a category...

```
FILTERS = (
    "lng > -105.980539 AND lng < -104.222726 AND lat < 40.959464 AND lat > 38.835483",
    "ANY categories.categoryId IN {2}"
)
RESULTS = 3 MERCHANTS IN RECT
```

However, this fetch isn't filtering down to the selected categories.  It's still returning 3 merchants.  Here's what merchantsForDisplay looks like when looped over and logged...

```
MERCHANT 16695
...HAS CATEGORY 1
MERCHANT 16719
...HAS CATEGORY 1
...HAS CATEGORY 2
MERCHANT 16712
...HAS CATEGORY 1
```

I'm at a complete loss understanding why my "ANY categories.categoryId IN %@" isn't working.  Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *restrict* the result to the objects with the given category, you have to
use `andPredicateWithSubpredicates`, not `orPredicateWithSubpredicates`, in

```
merchantsForDisplay = [MNMerchant MR_findAllSortedBy:@"sortName" ascending:YES withPredicate:[NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:filters]];
```

*Remark:* I would recommend not to use `stringWithFormat` at all when building
predicates, because it handles quoting, escaping and format specifiers differently
from `predicateWithFormat`.

Comment: OMG.  That's embarrassing.  Thank you.